# Apply styling to trailing zeroes in an Angular (5) "correct" way

Tags: javascript, angular

I'd like to modify the font-weight and color of the trailing zeroes of a number. Using a number pipe I'm able to specify 8 decimals, but I'd like all those added zeroes to have less visual significance than the rest of the number. How can I accomplish this in the most Angular "correct" way possible?

Please see the below image for a visual representation of what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image: illustration of numbers with trailing zeroes in a different style]

Comment: Is it only for `.0`?

Comment: Yes @DanielB, any trailing zeroes behind the decimal point. For example, in the case of the number `150.403` I'd like to display `150.40300000` with all the zeroes after the `3` to have a different style.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not achieve this functionality by creating your own custom pipe. This is caused by the fact, that applying custom font color is related to the container where a given text is displayed. Pipes ought to remain independent of the container (they simply manipulate raw data). That is why you should create your own directive. Here you have working example:

```
 @Component ({
  selector: 'my-selector',
  template: `<div myTextHighlight>1.543020000</div>`
})
export class AppComponent {
}

@Directive({
  selector: '[myTextHighlight]'
})
export class HighlightDirective implements OnInit{
  private element: ElementRef;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    setTimeout(()=> {
      let originalHTML = this.element.nativeElement.innerHTML;
      let whitePart = Number.parseFloat(originalHTML).toString();
      let greyPart = originalHTML.substring(whitePart.length, originalHTML.length);
      this.element.nativeElement.innerHTML = 
        `<span style='color: white'>${whitePart}</span>
        <span style='color: darkgrey'>${greyPart}</span>`;
    });
  }

  constructor(el: ElementRef) {
    el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
    this.element = el;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why cannot this "for sure" not be achieved with a custom pipe? I posted an answer showing exactly how that can be done...

Comment: I was not precise enough here. I meant that using pipes for this scenario is wrong approach, as they are not meant for such tasks. You can see that in your solution, where you had to use impure pipe and disable Angular's built-in sanitization. Question asks about the most Angular correct way, and documentation discourages both

Comment: I really think you should edit your answer then, because you are correct in your comment but incorrect in your answer stating that it isn't possible.

Comment: @Tinki it seems as though the `innerHTML` of all my elements is nothing. Perhaps the directive is being initialized before the data is populated (the values are not hard coded but rather loaded from an array through an `*ngFor` loop). Is there a way to ensure the directive updates the `innerHTML` whenever the value changes?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't seem to work even for hardcoded values such as in your example. Have you had success running it? `innerHTML` is empty.

Comment: @Tinki any updates on this? Can you provide a working example of your answer? I am unable to verify that this works.

Comment: I modified my answer. It has right now fully working example (personally tested;)

Comment: Great thank you! One minor adjustment I had to make is to trim whitespace from the `originalHTML`, for some reason a bunch of it snuck in there. Anyhow, this worked perfectly. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It's very much possible to use a custom pipe for this effect. You can replace the trailing zeroes in the pipe with your own custom `<span>` element with a class that you can style however you want.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({ name: 'fadeTrailingZeroes', pure: false })
export class FadeTrailingZeroes implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(public sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  }
  transform(text: string): SafeHtml {
    if (text) {
      return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(
        text.replace(/([0-9]+(\.[1-9]+)?)(\.?0+$)/g,"$1<span class='fade'>$3</span>")
      );
    } else {
      return text;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a working example at [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pipe-3kzrjx).

Please note that the *last* entry doesn't work, but that is due to my rather bad regex skills. The example should be sufficient enough to prove that it's possible to achieve the desired outcome with a custom pipe.

Comment: This does not seem to work as-is, I'm getting the following error when using your code `SafeValue must use [property]=binding:...`.